# Pandas: Split Row in multiple Rows based on Delimiter in Specific Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'ASSET_CLASS': ['Core',],
'SPLIT': ['0.6 Government / 0.4 Credit']})

display(df)

    ASSET_CLASS SPLIT
0   Core        0.6 Government / 0.4 Credit
```

My objective is to split the row into two rows by specifying the forward slash symbol as delimiter in column "SPLIT". Ideally, this is what I aim to obtain:

```
    ASSET_CLASS SPLIT
0   Core        0.6 Government
1   Core        0.4 Credit
```

Is there a way to achieve this using the explode function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `split` and `explode`:

```
df["SPLIT"] = df["SPLIT"].str.split(" / ")
df = df.explode("SPLIT").reset_index(drop=True)

>>> df
  ASSET_CLASS           SPLIT
0        Core  0.6 Government
1        Core      0.4 Credit
```

Comment: works perfectly well - thanks a lot!!!